# removing notes from a string with regex (in access VBA)

Tags: regex, vba

I have an issue with something that seems rather trivial but it ain't working, so I'm wondering what I am overlooking.

I have following string :

```
Just some blablabla with some notes on the end *1 *2
```

and I need to strip the 'notes' from the string so that it becomes as follows :

```
Just some blablabla with some notes on the end
```

My regex is as follows :

```
regex.Pattern = "^(.*)(\*[0-9]+\s?)+$"
```

So basically what it should do is look at the end of the string to see if it can find an asterisk followed by one or more integers and an optional space. Unfortunatly if I run this the way I stated it only removes the last note, and leaves the first as below

```
Just some blablabla with some notes on the end *1
```

Where is my logic going wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on your regex is that you are using a greedy operator:

```
^(.*)(\*[0-9]+\s?)+$
   ^----- here
```

Change it to a lazy one (or ungreedy) by adding a `?` so it will match the first match of `*1`

```
^(.*?)(\*[0-9]+\s?)+$
    ^---- here
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wC3yJ4/1)**

[image]

As an additional note, you could use this regex too:

```
^(.*?)\*\d
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `(.*)`, which is greedy. As the engine backtracks, the second group only matches once. Change `(.*)` to a match-aware construct, see the following regex:

```
^([^*]+|\*(?!\d))+(\*[0-9]+\s?)+$
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/qA7oW7/1).

Or you can use a [reluctant match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25728576/3622940) from [Fede's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25791454/3622940) as well, though mine is optimal.